# Skipping the output of identical values in subsequent rows

Tags: sql-server-2005

friends

I want following type of output with sql query from tbale tblABC

```
  OUTPUT
  ======

  SrNo.         Date               BillNo            Amount
  =================================================
     1         10-02-2012            VAT-1            1200.00
     2                               RET-4              50.00
     3                               RET-5             150.50
     4         11-02-2012            VAT-2            1500.00
     5                               RET-6            2505.00
     6         12-02-2012            VAT-3              05.00
```

from table which has following data

```
     tblABC
     ======

     SrNo.         Date               BillNo            Amount
     =================================================
     1         10-02-2012            VAT-1            1200.00
     2         10-02-2012            RET-4              50.00
     3         10-02-2012            RET-5             150.50
     4         11-02-2012            VAT-2            1500.00
     5         11-02-2012            RET-6            2505.00
     6         12-02-2012            VAT-3              05.00
```

The diffrence between the OUTPUT i want and   table is that in
OUTPUT i don't want Date Reptetion   as it is in table.

Please help how   could i have it.

Comment: show your code if you done for last output?

Comment: Why do you need SQL Server to leave this value out for you? Can't your client application, which has to loop through row by row anyway when it displays the data, keep track of the last value and not show it if the current one is the same?

Comment: select SrNo, BillNo, Credit, GrossAmt as Amount from tbABC

Comment: Because it will make report slow

Comment: Loop will take lot of time in case of Large amount data

Comment: no. It won't.. not that much.. If you want to do it in sql, probably you have to do the same as u create a temp table or view, throw in ur result to that table and do what Aaron mentioned in a loop. Select the result again..

Comment: Loop will take a lot of time? If you're outputting the data to the client, do you think you are not using a loop? Do you think making SQL Server perform a loop, essentially, *in addition* to your client performing a loop, is going to be faster than piggybacking off the loop you're already doing on the client? Or less complicated?

Comment: As an aside, DD-MM-YYYY is an absolutely horrible choice for an output format. How many of your users do you think will understand that is February 10th and not October 2nd? I strongly recommend you stick to an unambiguous date format. It is helpful for your users and for folks here to figure out what you mean.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - DD-MM-YYYY is a horrible format for sorting but afaik, very understandable to all french and belgian people. It's the MM-DD-YYYY that get's *me* tripped up every time <g>.

Comment: @Lieven I didn't say MM-DD-YYYY was any better. In fact I think it's even worse. But when you say YYYY-MM-DD, as I posted in my answer, no user from any country can be confused.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - True (upvoted your answer already) but in the end, the data has to be presented to a user. Our users are accustomed to DD-MM-YYYY. The DD-MM-YYYY format is on most (if not all) official documents I ever received.

Comment: Ok but when posting here please use unambiguous date formats that aren't going to be confusing. What you want in the output is one thing but at least make it possible for us to be able to tell what month the input falls in.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tblABC TABLE
(
    SrNo INT, [Date] DATETIME, BillNo CHAR(5), Amount DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT @tblABC SELECT 1,'20120210','VAT-1',1200.00
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'20120210','RET-4',50.00
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'20120210','RET-5',150.50
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'20120211','VAT-2',1500.00
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'20120211','RET-6',2505.00
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'20120212','VAT-3',05.00;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT SrNo, [Date] = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), [Date], 103), '/', '-'), 
    BillNo, Amount, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY SrNo)
    FROM @tblAbC
)
SELECT SrNo, [Date] = CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN [Date] ELSE '' END, BillNo, Amount
  FROM x 
  ORDER BY SrNo;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron your answer is right but i am unable to get at rn (RowNumber) when i executed Query then in ouput rn starts counting from 1 till it not get different date . I am not getting how it(rn) is again starting from 1  for next date

Comment: The window function uses PARTITION BY (grouping) and ORDER BY (ranking) to assign numbers. In English, take all the rows with the same date, and then hand out 1,2,3 etc. based on the value of SrNo. Now repeat for the next distinct date. In the output we just conditionally show the dates where they were "first" in their grouping.

Answer (score -1):

use Case keyword in select statement.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: This isn't a very helpful answer. Can you explain how simply adding a case expression to the select list will help here?