# Join two tables, only use latest value of right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to join 2 tables, but only join with the latest record in a group of records.

The left table:

**Part**

- Part.PartNum

The right table:

**Material**

- Material.Partnum
- Material.Formula
- Material.RevisionNum

The revision number starts at "A" and increases.

I would like to join the 2 tables by PartNum, but only join with the latest record from right table. I have seen other examples on SO but an having a hard time putting it all together.

Edit:

I found out the first revision number is "New", then it increments A,B,...  It will never be more than one or two revisions, so I am not worried about going over the sequence.  But how do I choose the latest one with 'New' being the first revision number?

Comment: Please specify what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: How does RevisionNum increase? Is it always a single character? If so, what would happen at the 27th revision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general SQL statement that would run this would be:

```
select P.PartNum, M.Formula, M.RevisionNum
from Parts P
join Material M on P.PartNum = M.PartNum
where M.RevisionNum = (select max(M2.RevisionNum) from Material M2
                       where M2.PartNum = P.PartNum);
```

Repeating the above caveats about what happens after Revision #26.  The max(RevisionNum) may break depending upon what happens after #26.

---

EDIT:

If RevisionNum sequence always starts w/ NEW and then continues, A, B, C, etc., then the max() needs to be replaced w/ something more complicated (and messy):

```
select P.PartNum, M.RevisionNum
from Parts P
join Material M on P.PartNum = M.PartNum
where (
      (select count(*) from Material M2 
              where M2.PartNum = P.PartNum) > 1
      and M.RevisionNum = (select max(M3.RevisionNum) from Material M3
                   where M3.PartNum = P.PartNum and M3.RevisionNum <> 'NEW')
      )
      or ( 
      (select count(*) from Material M4
              where M4.PartNum = P.PartNum) = 1
       and M.RevisionNum = 'NEW'
      )
```

There must be a better way to do this.  This works though -- will have to think about a faster solution.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70c19/3

Comment: See the addition.  It's messy -- I'm thinking there must be a better way -- maybe I'll think of it during lunch!

Answer (score 5):

If SQL Server 2005+

```
;WITH m AS 
(
   SELECT Partnum, Formula, RevisionNum,
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartNum ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN RevisionNum ='New' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
     FROM dbo.Material
)
SELECT p.PartNum, m.Formula, m.RevisionNum
FROM dbo.Parts AS p
INNER JOIN m ON p.PartNum = m.PartNum
WHERE m.rn = 1;
```

Though curious, what do you do when there are more than 26 revisions (e.g. what comes after `Z`)?

Comment: This worked. Could you take a minute to explain why it worked?

Comment: Well of course it no longer works. You changed the problem. I've updated but in the future you may save people a lot of work and re-work if you state the full problem up front.

Comment: As for how it works, I gave a brief explanation here. It's referencing different columns but the concept is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495699/skipping-the-output-of-identical-values-in-subsequent-rows/9495806#comment12031034_9495806

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005+ as well:

**Updated** to handle OPs changing requirements

```
SELECT P.PartNum,
       M.Formula,
       M.RevisionNum
FROM Part AS P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Material AS M
    WHERE M.Partnum = P.PartNum
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN RevisionNum ='New' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
             M.RevisionNum DESC
) AS M
```